# How to prevent classes to be overridden in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm setting up rules how to write minitests, and I want to prevent other programmers to override methods for existing classes, because it will affect other tests, where this class will be used. Here is some clarifications below.

For example, I have a class in the lib folder, **KlassExample**. It has a public method **do_something** with own logic. In minitest someone could want to override this method with other logic. I want to not allow run test, if the class logic was overridden.

Code samples:

**lib/klass_example.rb**

```rb
class KlassExample

  def do_something
    false
  end

end
```

**test/unit/lib/klass_example_test.rb**

```rb
require 'unit/test_helper'
require 'klass_example'

class KlassExample

  def do_something
    true
  end

end

class KlassExampleTest < Minitest::Test

  def test_do_something
    assert_equal true, KlassExample.new.do_something
  end

end
```

I want that programmers would use **MiniTest::Mock** instead of class overriding, so I need some coercive actions to get them to write code in the right way.

Is there any possible complex solution how to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You never override anything in your code samples.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using a mock for this, either! Since `KlassExample` is the test subject, you should be testing its behaviour directly.

Comment: Rather than coming up with some complex/convoluted solution, this is something I have always solved through code reviews. It should be quite obvious if something is *redefining a method* inside the test. There's also [this rubocop rule](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/SubjectStub) to help prevent such bad practice, though I'm not certain if there's an equivalent cop for minitest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this particular use case might be somewhat covered with [`TracePoint#new(:class)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html) by setting a `TracePoint` on the class re-opening and e.g. raising from there, you would never prevent *all* the possibilities explicitly and implicitly built into Ruby to indeed *allow* developers to do whatever they want.

Overwritten [`Module#prepended`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepended) callback would disallow others to `prepend` modules to your class:

```
KlassExample.prepend(Module.new { def self.prepended(*); raise end })
```

There are ways to prevent [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method) calls, also they are already looking like hacks.

But the whole set of possibilities to fool your guard in nearly infinite, so I doubt it’s doable in general. I bet every time you would think “ok, now everything is covered,” I’d easily invent another cumbersome way to bypass all your guards.

Ruby is not the language designed to *prevent* developers from doing whatever they want.